# How to echo the '<?php' in HTML without starting a php section

Tags: php, html

the Title descripe it:

How to echo the `<?php` open tag, without starting a `<?php` section.
I tried it with this:

```
$string = str_replace("<?php","<?php",$string);
```

I hope someone can help me! :)

Kind regards,
Leo

Comment: Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) any time you want to echo anything in HTML that has... HTML special characters.

Comment: I don't understand your code. You're replacing a string with itself, what's the point of that?

Comment: Echoing `<?php` won't start a PHP section. PHP only processes the file contents, not the output that it echoes.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question there. The `htmlspecialchars` helped me with this: `$string = str_replace("<?php","htmlsepcialchars("<?php")",$string);`

Comment: For some reason I feel like I didn't really help that much.

Comment: Barmar the string echo a Post from the database. This here: `$string = str_replace("\n","<br>",$i["post"]);
` and I use him for the next replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not recursively embeddable. The following

```
<?php

echo "<?php echo 'Hi mom!' ?>";
```

Will output the literal characters `<`, `?`, `p` etc... The "internal" echo will NOT be executed, because it's not PHP code - it's just some characters in a string.

Note that if you're outputting this text into an HTML context (e.g. a web browser), the `<?php` tag WILL be mis-interpreted as an invalid/illegal HTML tag, and be skipped by the browser. In which case, you have to do

```
echo "&lt;?php echo 'hi mom!' ?&gt;"
```

Remember - you're not outputting PHP code, you're outputting text, and if it's going into a web page, that text has to be VALID html.